# Expected a type, but TYPENAME has kind ‘* -> *’

Tags: haskell

I am having issues with an error I don't understand

**Code**:

```
mergHufffman::(String,Int) -> (String,Int) -> (String,Int)
mergHufffman x y = (fst x ++ fst y, snd x + snd y)


data HTree a = Leaf a | Branch (HTree a) (HTree a) deriving Show


treeHuff::[(String,Int)] -> HTree
treeHuff (x:[]) = Leaf x
treeHuff (x:y:[])
        | snd x < snd y = Branch Leaf x Leaf y
        | snd x > snd y = Branch Leaf y Leaf x
treeHuff (x:y:z:list)
        | snd x > snd merged = Branch (Leaf x) (treeHuff y:z:list)
        | otherwise = Branch (treeHuff y:z:[]) (treeHuff x:list)
        where merged = mergHufffman y z
```

**Error**:

```
Expecting one more argument to ‘HTree’
    Expected a type, but ‘HTree’ has kind ‘* -> *’
    In the type signature for ‘treeHuff’:
      treeHuff :: [(String, Int)] -> HTree
```

If possible can you explain both the error, and where I made it.

**Solution**:

Thanks to Sepp2k and Carsten I fixed the issue.

```
mergHufffman::(String,Int) -> (String,Int) -> (String,Int)
mergHufffman x y =  (fst x ++ fst y, snd x + snd y)

data HTree a = Leaf a | Branch (HTree a) (HTree a) deriving Show

treeHuff::[(String,Int)] -> HTree (String,Int)
treeHuff (x:[]) = Leaf x
treeHuff (x:y:[])
        | snd x < snd y = Branch (Leaf x) (Leaf y)
        | snd x > snd y = Branch (Leaf y) (Leaf x)
treeHuff (x:y:z:list)
        | snd x > snd merged = Branch (Leaf x) (treeHuff $ sortFirst $ y:z:list)
        | otherwise = Branch (treeHuff $ y:z:[]) (treeHuff $ sortFirst $ x:list)
        where merged = mergHufffman y z 

sortFirst::[(String,Int)]->[(String,Int)]
sortFirst freq = reverse $ sortBy (comparing snd) freq

readHuffTree :: HTree (String,Int)-> String -> [(String, String)]
readHuffTree (Branch x y) code = f1 ++ f2
                          where 
                          f1 = readHuffTree x (code ++ "0")
                          f2 = readHuffTree y (code ++ "1")
readHuffTree (Leaf x) code = ((fst x, code):[])
```

Comment: it's the last part of `treeHuff :: [(String,Int)] -> HTree` - the last is no **type** yet - you need to provide a type for the `a` int `HTree a` - in this case `HTree (String,Int)` (or so it seems)

Comment: The error message **says** that HTree is expecting one more argument, and pinpoints exactly where it's expecting it.

Comment: To make matters more confusing, the word "type" sometimes refers to type-level entities of all kinds, and sometimes only to those of kind `*` or `#`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message is telling you that `HTree` is not a type until you give it one more argument. That is `HTree String` or `HTree Int` would be types, but `HTree` by itself is not.

Another way of putting it: when you say "I want to return a tree", Haskell asks "A tree of what?".